# Asymptotic distance between $x^2+1$ primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

As I recall, the most common difference between consecutive primes starts with $2$, moves on to $6$, then $30$, and is conjectured to progress like the primorials over a long time, without bound.

Is there any analogous prediction about $x^2+1$ or other polynomial prime gaps?

Comment: IIRC it is unknown whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2+1$. So kinda difficult to make a prediction like this.

Comment: polynomoal remander theorem not enough for you.

Comment: simply using the first two terms, and some modular arithmetic, I can tell you any $x$ that could create primes all end in 0,4, or 6. for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those things are conjectured by the random model for the primes, the model on which every conjecture about primes is based. This model is saying that when $n$ is picked uniformly in $[1,N]$, for $p\le N^r$ then $n\bmod p$ is uniformly distributed in $1,\ldots, p$ and it is independent from one $p$ to the other. Of course this model is wrong for a fixed $N$, what we assume is that it gets less wrong as $N\to \infty$, ultimately giving correct predictions.

- What is $r$ ? It is the constant $r\in [1/2,1)$ such that the probability that $n$ (picked uniformly in $[1,N]$) is prime is $$\prod_{p \le N^r} Pr(p\nmid n)=\prod_{p \le N^r} (1-p^{-1})$$

  This $r$ can be evaluated from Mertens' theorem and the PNT : it is $r=e^{-\gamma}$, the only constant such that $$\lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{\prod_{p \le N^r} (1-p^{-1})}{\pi(N)/N}=\lim_{N \to \infty}\log N\prod_{p \le N^r} (1-p^{-1})=1$$
- The probability that $n,n+2$ are both primes is
  $$\prod_{p \le N^r} Pr(p\nmid n,p\nmid n+2)=(1-2^{-1})\prod_{3\le p \le N^r} (1-2 p^{-1})$$

  The conjectured number of twin primes $\le N$ is $$C_2\frac{N}{\log^2 N}\sim N(1-2^{-1})\prod_{3\le p \le N^r} (1-2 p^{-1})$$ where $C_2$ is the [twin prime constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) $$C_2=\lim_{N\to \infty}(\log^2 N) (1-2^{-1})\prod_{3\le p \le N^r} (1-2 p^{-1})=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{(1-2^{-1})\prod_{3\le p \le N^r} (1-2 p^{-1})}{\prod_{ p \le N^r} (1- p^{-1})^2}$$
- The probability that $n^2+1$ is prime is $$\prod_{p\le N^{2r}} Pr(p\nmid n^2+1)= (1-2^{-1})\prod_{p\le N^{2r},p\equiv 1\bmod 4} (1-2 p^{-1})$$

  Thus the conjectured number of primes $n^2+1$ with $n\le N$ is $$A \frac{N}{\log N}$$ where the [obtained constant is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture) $$A = \lim_{N\to \infty}(\log N) (1-2^{-1})\prod_{p\le N^{2r},p\equiv 1\bmod 4} (1-2 p^{-1})$$ $$= \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{(1-2^{-1})\prod_{p\le N^{2r},p\equiv 1\bmod 4} (1-2 p^{-1})}{\frac12 \prod_{p\le N^{2r}}(1-p^{-1})}$$

  And the conjectured mean distance between two consecutive such primes $n^2+1,n_2^2+1$ is $$A\log n$$

Comment: all $x>2$ need to end in 0,4 or 6 to produce primes.

Comment: so what ? ${}{}$

Comment: I have seen Mertens third theorem written like $\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln N\prod_{p\le N}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=e^{-\gamma}$ from there I see that writing $N^{\gamma}$ in the index instead should make the product bigger but I can't see why it should be exactly 1, could you give me some hint?, thanks

Comment: I messed up it is $r=e^{-\gamma}$ not $r = \gamma$ (indeed they are almost equal) and it disappears in the obtained infinite products for the constants $C_2,A$

Comment: I didn't even realize there was an error but is nice you found it what I feel confused about is why is possible to pass from $\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln N\prod_{p\le N}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=c$ to $\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln N\prod_{p\le N^c}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=1$, as far as I can understand the rest seems fine to me so not sure why you say it disappears in C_2 and A, I'm sorry and thanks again

Comment: It is just $\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln N\prod_{p\le N}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=c \implies $ $\lim_{N\to\infty} \ln N\prod_{p\le N^c}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac1c\ln N^c\prod_{p\le N^c}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$ $=\lim_{M\to\infty} \frac1c\ln M\prod_{p\le M}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=\frac{c}{c}$

Comment: Thanks, I realize now what I was asking was pretty basic, sorry about that