# Number of twin primes

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, euler-product

I am reading article about pseudorandomness of primes and there is a part that I don't understand. 
Based on Cramer model(without even numbers) the number of twin primes in $[1,..,N]$ 
is ~ $2\frac{N}{log^2(N)}$.

Then in general, assume that all numbers n divisible by some
prime less than a small threshold w are prime with probability zero,
and are prime with a probability of $\Pi_{p<w} (1-\frac{1}{p})^{-1} \frac{1}{logN}$ otherwise.

Then the number of twin primes ~ $2 \Pi_{p<w} (1-\frac{1}{p^2}) \frac{N}{log^2N}$, and if $w \to \infty$ then we got $\Pi_{2} \frac{N}{log^2N}$, where $\Pi_{2}=2 \Pi_{p \geq 3} (1-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2})$.

I wonder how we get $(1-\frac{1}{p^2})$ in this prediction and $(1-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2})$ in twin prime constant? I know this is Euler product formula but I cannot figure out the right calculations.
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor $1-\frac1{p^2}$ is wrong. It should be $1-\frac1{(p-1)^2}$ there, too; there's no difference in this regard when you take $w\to\infty$.

The factor $1-\frac1{(p-1)^2}$ arises from a correction for the fact that the estimate $\log^{-2}N$ for the density of twin primes incorrectly assumes that the events of $x$ and $x+2$ not being divisible by a prime $p$ are independent. This assumption yields $\left(1-\frac1p\right)^2$ for the probability of both of these events to occur, whereas for odd primes the correct probability would be $1-\frac2p$. To correct for this, the estimate is multiplied by the ratio

$$
\frac{1-\frac2p}{\left(1-\frac1p\right)^2}=\frac{p^2-2p}{(p-1)^2}=1-\frac1{(p-1)^2}
$$

for each odd prime $p$.

See my answer to [Heuristics of counting twin primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3475496) for more on this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3466344/276986 for how I obtain this (and every other) constant. ie. $\left(1-\frac1p\right)^2$ doesn't represent a probability, it is part of the $\log^2 N$ term

Comment: @reuns: Thanks, that's really interesting! I didn't know that the cutoff near $\sqrt N$ can be made precise in this way with $\gamma$.