# Do the numbers preceding primes have on an average fewer divisors than the numbers succeeding primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

I wanted to see if the numbers preceding primes behaved differently in any way form the numbers succeeding primes so I calculated at the average number of divisors of number of the form $p-1$ and $p+1$ where $p$ is a prime.

Let $d(n)$ be the number of divisors of $n$. Define $f(x) = \sum_{p \le x} d(p-1)$ and $g(x) = \sum_{p \le x} d(p+1)$ where $p$ is a prime. I observed that there are only $3251$ instances where $f(x) < g(x)$. The largest value of $x$ for which this is true is $x = 3752789$. After checking till $x \le 1.9 \times 10^{10}$, I could not find the inequality reversing again.

This the data shows that the numbers preceding primes have on a average fewer number of divisors than the numbers succeeding primes. The graph below shows the actual data.

**Question**: Is there any reason why this should be true?

[image]

**Source code**

```
import numpy
p = 2
i = fd = fp = 0
d1 = d2 = p1 = p2 = 0
target = step = 10^6

while True:
    i  = i + 1  
    d1 = d1 + len(divisors(p-1))
    d2 = d2 + len(divisors(p+1))
    if d1 > d2:
        fd = fd + 1
    
    p1 = p1 + len(prime_factors(p-1))
    p2 = p2 + len(prime_factors(p+1))
    if p1 > p2:
        fp = fp + 1
        
    if i > target:
        print i,p,d1,d2,fd, d2-d1,(d2-d1)/i.n(), p1,p2,fp, p2-p1
        target = target + step
        
    p = next_prime(p)
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is the difference significant?  I mean...what does $|f(x)-g(x)|$ look like?  Or $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$.

Comment: reminds me of [this similar but different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491929/why-do-even-numbers-which-surround-primes-have-more-divisors-than-those-which-su)

Comment: One possible reason, but I haven't investigated how significant it can be, is that, at least for smaller primes, the primes modulo $3$ have more congruent to $2$ than $1$ (e.g., see the answer to MO's [Consecutive Primes mod 3](https://mathoverflow.net/q/154739/129887)) and the primes modulo $4$ have more congruent to $3$ than $1$ (e.g., see the answer to MO's [A "bit" of primes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/128079/129887)). This similar issue appears to also be the case for some other modulos, at least for smaller primes.

Comment: Related to my comment above, I only skimmed through the paper, but it seems the first part of it which you can access from arXiv at [Prime Number Races](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408319) has some possible useful information for you. For example, near the bottom of page #$5$, it says the # of primes less than $x$ of the form $3n + 1$ out-number those of $3n + 2$ first only at $x  = 608\text{,}981\text{,}813\text{,}029$.

Comment: $\sum_{3k \le x} d(3k)=5/9(x\log x)+O(x)$ while the others (on $3k \pm 1$) are $(2/9)x\log x +O(x)$ each, so it is a $5/2$ ratio in the main term- I expect the fact that $3n+2$ wins the prime race so much oftener and $3n+3$ succeeds it, explains the data; proving it though may be quite hard

Comment: @lulu $g(x)-f(x)$ fluctuates. For the first $3.9 \times 10^6$ primes it is $325774$. For the first $9.2 \times 10^6$ primes it is $654997$. For the first $11.2 \times 10^7$ it is $302853$. My code is running. It will be interesting to see if it drops below zero for some large value of $x$.

Comment: One reason might be that bigger numbers tend to have more divisors than smaller numbers ($p+1>p-1$).

Comment: @lulu Added a graph which quantifies how large or significant the difference is

Comment: @JohnBentin Based on your comment, I did some computation. I don't think that being bigger is the only reason because data shows that the proportion of integer pairs $n,n+2$ such that $d(n) > d(n+2)$ is equal to the proportion of integer pairs $n,n+2$ such that $d(n) < d(n+2)$. If bigger was the sole reason then the proportion of $d(n) < d(n+2)$ should have been detectably greater

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment,

For $a=\pm 1$
$$\sum_p d(p -a)p^{-s}=\sum_{k\ge 1} \sum_{lk+a \ prime} (lk+a)^{-s}=\sum_{k\ge 1} \sum_{\chi\bmod k} \frac{\chi(a)}{\varphi(k)}\sum_p \chi(p)p^{-s}$$

$$\sum_p (d(p-1)-d(p+1))p^{-s}=\sum_k \sum_{\chi\bmod k} \frac{1-\chi(-1)}{\varphi(k)}\sum_p \chi(p)p^{-s}$$

Under the GRH each term is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1/2$,

If $\chi^2$ is a non-trivial character then $\sum_p \chi(p)p^{-s}$ is analytic at $s=1/2$, if $\chi$ is a quadratic character then as $s\to 1/2^+$ $$\sum_p \chi(p)p^{-s}=\sum_{m\ge 1}\frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log L(sm,\chi^m)\sim \frac{1}2\log(s-1/2)$$

thus $$\lim_{s\to 1/2^+}\frac{ \frac{1-\chi(-1)}{\varphi(k)}\sum_p \chi(p)p^{-s}}{\log(s-1/2)} =\frac{1_{\chi \text{ is a quadratic odd character}}}{\varphi(k)}$$
Is this not too bad to conjecture that ? $$\lim_{s\to 1/2^+}\sum_p (d(p-1)-d(p+1))p^{-s}=\color{red}{-\infty}$$
Estimating the growth of $\sum_{p\le x} d(p-1)-d(p+1)$ thus the abscissa of convergence of the Dirichlet series would help.