# Finite simple groups of order $p+1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Are there any well known patterns about which finite simple groups have order $ p+1 $ for $ p $ a prime?

Here is a list of all non-cyclic simple groups of order up to 100,000 and whether they have order p+1 (there are 31 such groups, 16 have order $ p+1 $)

$ PSL_2(5) $, $p=59$

$ PSL_2(7) $, $p=167$

$ PSL_2(9) $, $p=359$

$ PSL_2(8) $, $p=503$

$ PSL_2(11) $, $p=659$

$ PSL_2(13) $, $p=1091$

$ PSL_2(17) $, $p=2447$

$ A_7 $, $2519$ not prime

$ PSL_2(19) $, $3419$ not prime

$ PSL_2(16) $, $p=4079$

$ PSL_3(3) $, $5615$ not prime

$ PSU_3(3) $, $p=6047$

$ PSL_2(23) $, $6071$ not prime

$ PSL_2(25) $, $7799$ not prime

$ M_{11} $, $p=7919$

$ PSL_2(27) $, $9827$ not prime

$ PSL_2(29) $, $12,179$ not prime

$ PSL_2(31) $, $p=14,879$

$ PSL_4(2) $, $20,159$ not prime

$ PSL_3(4) $, $20,159$ not prime

$ PSL_2(37) $, $p=25,307$

$ PSU_4(2) $, $p=25,919$

$ Suz(8) $, $29,119$ not prime

$ PSL_2(32) $, $32,735$ not prime

$ PSL_2(41) $, $p=34,439$

$ PSL_2(43) $, $p=39,731$

$ PSL_2(47) $, $51,887$ not prime

$ PSL_2(49) $, $58,799$ not prime

$ PSU_3(4) $, $62,399$ not prime

$ PSL_2(53) $, $p=74,411$

$ M_{12} $, $95,039$ not prime

Comment: First thought:  there are probably more such (nonabelian) simple groups than the PNT would predict, thanks to heuristics about how many divisors $p+1$ has (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491929/why-do-even-numbers-which-surround-primes-have-more-divisors-than-those-which-su).

Comment: Since most families of finite simple groups have polynomial order in the size of an underlying field, you could probably prove that there exist infinitely many examples (and estimate their frequency) conditionally on the Bateman-Horn conjecture.  The case of $A_n$ is probably harder to say things about.  But I suspect that the only unconditional answer you'll get is for the groups of prime order.

Comment: The alternating groups $A_n$ for $n=5,6,9,31,41,373,589$ are of this form, and these are the only ones up to $n=800$.

Comment: And $n=812,989$ up to $1000$. Looks like there might be infinitely many such $n$. The latter of these has 2534 digits and ends with 240 9s.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven http://oeis.org/A082671

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki It never ceases to amaze me what sort of things people have uploaded to that database.

Comment: Of the simple non-abelian groups up to order $10^{20}$, there are $40007$ orders of the form $p+1$, for prime $p$.  The only pattern I've seen is that the vast majority are $\operatorname{PSL}(2,q)$s, which is what one would expect.  The largest non-PSL in that list is the Janko group $J_4$ of order $86775571046077562879 + 1$.

Comment: @James how many simple non-abelian groups of order up to $ 10^{20} $ are there? (just to get a sense of $ 40,007 $ orders of the form $ p+1 $ out of how many)

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira The number of orders of simple non-abelian groups up to $10^{20}$ is $403864$, but some of those are the order of two distinct groups. If my script is correct, that would add another $6$ actual groups to that number.

Comment: Are you interested in some more primes of the form $\frac{n!}{2}-1$ ?  Slight correction , for $n=989$ , we get a $2535$-digit prime ending with $244$ nines. [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=n%21%2F2-1&use=n&perpage=20&format=1&sent=1&PR=1&PRP=1&U=1&VP=1&EV=1&OD=1&VC=1&n=1001) are the next ones.

Comment: [this one](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000002673727688) is already really large.

Comment: and [this one](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000002673727590) seems to be the largest one factordb knows.